# Why is random() * random() different to random() ** 2?

Tags: python, random

Is there are difference between `random() * random()` and `random() ** 2`? `random()` returns a value between 0 and 1 from a uniform distribution.

When testing both versions of random square numbers I noticed a little difference. I created 100000 random square numbers and counted how many numbers are in each interval of 0.01 (0.00 to 0.01, 0.01 to 0.02, ...). It seems that these versions of squared random number generation are different.

Squaring a random number instead of multiplying two random numbers has you reuse a random number, but I think the distribution should remain the same. Is there really a difference? If not, why is my test showing a difference?

---

I generate two random binned distributions for `random() * random()` and one for `random() ** 2` like so:

```
from random import random

lst = [0 for i in range(100)]
lst2, lst3 = list(lst), list(lst)

#create two random distributions for random() * random()
for i in range(100000):
    lst[int(100 * random() * random())] += 1

for i in range(100000):
    lst2[int(100 * random() * random())] += 1

for i in range(100000):
    lst3[int(100 * random() ** 2)] += 1
```

which gives

```
>>> lst
[
    5626, 4139, 3705, 3348, 3085, 2933, 2725, 2539, 2449, 2413,
    2259, 2179, 2116, 2062, 1961, 1827, 1754, 1743, 1719, 1753,
    1522, 1543, 1513, 1361, 1372, 1290, 1336, 1274, 1219, 1178,
    1139, 1147, 1109, 1163, 1060, 1022, 1007,  952,  984,  957,
     906,  900,  843,  883,  802,  801,  710,  752,  705,  729,
     654,  668,  628,  633,  615,  600,  566,  551,  532,  541,
     511,  493,  465,  503,  450,  394,  405,  405,  404,  332,
     369,  369,  332,  316,  272,  284,  315,  257,  224,  230,
     221,  175,  209,  188,  162,  156,  159,  114,  131,  124,
     96,   94,   80,   73,   54,   45,   43,   23,   18,     3
]

>>> lst2
[
    5548, 4218, 3604, 3237, 3082, 2921, 2872, 2570, 2479, 2392,
    2296, 2205, 2113, 1990, 1901, 1814, 1801, 1714, 1660, 1591,
    1631, 1523, 1491, 1505, 1385, 1329, 1275, 1308, 1324, 1207,
    1209, 1208, 1117, 1136, 1015, 1080, 1001,  993,  958,  948,
     903,  843,  843,  849,  801,  799,  748,  729,  705,  660,
     701,  689,  676,  656,  632,  581,  564,  537,  517,  525,
     483,  478,  473,  494,  457,  422,  412,  390,  384,  352,
     350,  323,  322,  308,  304,  275,  272,  256,  246,  265,
     227,  204,  171,  191,  191,  136,  145,  136,  108,  117,
      93,   83,   74,   77,   55,   38,   32,   25,   21,    1
]

>>> lst3
[
    10047, 4198, 3214, 2696, 2369, 2117, 2010, 1869, 1752, 1653,
     1552, 1416, 1405, 1377, 1328, 1293, 1252, 1245, 1121, 1146,
     1047, 1051, 1123, 1100,  951,  948,  967,  933,  939,  925,
      940,  893,  929,  874,  824,  843,  868,  800,  844,  822,
      746,  733,  808,  734,  740,  682,  713,  681,  675,  686,
      689,  730,  707,  677,  645,  661,  645,  651,  649,  672,
      679,  593,  585,  622,  611,  636,  543,  571,  594,  593,
      629,  624,  593,  567,  584,  585,  610,  549,  553,  574,
      547,  583,  582,  553,  536,  512,  498,  562,  536,  523,
      553,  485,  503,  502,  518,  554,  485,  482,  470,  516
]
```

The expected random error is the difference in the first two:

```
[
    78,  79, 101, 111,   3,  12, 147,  31,  30,  21,
    37,  26,   3,  72,  60,  13,  47,  29,  59, 162,
   109,  20,  22, 144,  13,  39,  61,  34, 105,  29,
    70,  61,   8,  27,  45,  58,   6,  41,  26,   9,
     3,  57,   0,  34,   1,   2,  38,  23,   0,  69,
    47,  21,  48,  23,  17,  19,   2,  14,  15,  16,
    28,  15,   8,   9,   7,  28,   7,  15,  20,  20,
    19,  46,  10,   8,  32,   9,  43,   1,  22,  35,
     6,  29,  38,   3,  29,  20,  14,  22,  23,   7,
     3,  11,   6,   4,   1,   7,  11,   2,   3,   2
]
```

But the difference between the first and third is much larger, hinting that the distributions are different:

```
[
    4421,   59,  491,  652,  716,  816,  715,  670,  697,  760,
     707,  763,  711,  685,  633,  534,  502,  498,  598,  607,
     475,  492,  390,  261,  421,  342,  369,  341,  280,  253,
     199,  254,  180,  289,  236,  179,  139,  152,  140,  135,
     160,  167,   35,  149,   62,  119,    3,   71,   30,   43,
      35,   62,   79,   44,   30,   61,   79,  100,  117,  131,
     168,  100,  120,  119,  161,  242,  138,  166,  190,  261,
     260,  255,  261,  251,  312,  301,  295,  292,  329,  344,
     326,  408,  373,  365,  374,  356,  339,  448,  405,  399,
     457,  391,  423,  429,  464,  509,  442,  459,  452,  513
]
```

Comment: by calling `random()` twice, you are getting 2 different numbers. where as `random()^2` is square - I dont see the confusion

Comment: You answered your own question: "by squaring a random number instead of multiplying two random numbers you reuse a random number".  Why do you think "the outcome should be the same"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about nonsense. there is no good explanation for the results that led to the question.

Comment: It's not a bad question, but perhaps it would be more on-topic at [math.se].

Comment: Consider two random variables, `a` and `b`. The difference between your two scenarios is between: 1. `a * b`, where `a` and `b` are (theoretically) independent (the `random() * random()` case), and 2. `a * b`, where `a = b`, and thus very much _not_ independent (the `pow(random(), 2)` case). The distributions of `a * b` would thus be very different, depending on whether `a` and `b` are independent.

Comment: Simplify this:  suppose `random()` returned either 0.0 or 1.0, and nothing else, each half the time.  Then `pow(random(), 2)` will return 0.0 or 1.0, each half the time.  But `random() * random()` will return 0.0 75% of the time, and 1.0 25% of the time.  The distributions are very different even in this very simple case.  Now  redo this analysis assuming `random()` returns 0.0, 0.5 or 1.0 uniformly at random.  Etc.  Repeat until the light dawns ;-)

Comment: I think that this is the question he is asking - if X and Y are uniform random variables on [0,1], why is the distribution of X^2 different than the distribution of X*Y. After the edit, should be moved to mathematics, but I'm feeling less comfortable with such a major edit

Comment: @TimPeters So you mean the two distributions are not different, but my test showed otherwise, because of the way I tested it? (test added to question) The way I see it, the two distributions become more alike if `random()` can return many values between 0.0 and 1.0 . I hope the light dawned.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here are some plots:

All the possibilities for `random() * random()`:

[image: A 2D heatmap with most intensity in the top-right.]

The x-axis is one random variable increasing rightwards, and the y-axis is another increasing upwards.

You can see that if either is low, the result will be low, and both have to be high to get a high result.

When the only decider is a single axis, as in the `random() ** 2` case, you get

[image: A 2D heatmap that increases quadratically from bottom to top, and is invariant in the x-axis]

In this it is far more likely to get a very dark (large) value, as the whole top is dark, not just a corner.

When you make both linearized, with `random() * random()` on top:

[image: A linearization of the first graph]
[image: A linearization of the second graph]

You see that the distributions are indeed different.

Code:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot
import matplotlib.cm

def make_fig(name, data):
    figure = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
    print(data.shape)
    figure.set_size_inches(data.shape[1]//100, data.shape[0]//100)

    axes = matplotlib.pyplot.Axes(figure, [0, 0, 1, 1])
    axes.set_axis_off()
    figure.add_axes(axes)

    axes.imshow(data, origin="lower", cmap=matplotlib.cm.Greys, aspect="auto")
    figure.savefig(name, dpi=200)

xs, ys = numpy.mgrid[:1000, :1000]
two_random = xs * ys

make_fig("two_random.png", two_random)

two_random_flat = two_random.flatten()
two_random_flat.sort()
two_random_flat = two_random_flat[::1000]

make_fig("two_random_1D.png", numpy.tile(two_random_flat, (100, 1)))

one_random = xs * xs

make_fig("one_random.png", one_random)

one_random_flat = one_random.flatten()
one_random_flat.sort()
one_random_flat = one_random_flat[::1000]

make_fig("one_random_1D.png", numpy.tile(one_random_flat, (100, 1)))
```

---

You can also approach this mathematically. The probability of getting a value less than `x`, with `0 ≤ x ≤ 1` is

#### For `random()²`:

```
√x
```

as the probability the random value being lower than `x` is the probability that `random()² < x`.

#### For `random() · random()`:

Given the first random variable is `r` and the second is `R`, we can find the probability that `Rr < x` with a fixed `R`:

```
P(Rr < x)
= P(r < x/R)
= 1 if x > R (and so x/R > 1)
or
= x/R otherwise
```

So we want

```
∫ P(Rr < x) dR from R=0 to R=1

= ∫ 1   dR from R=0 to R=x
+ ∫ x/R dR from R=x to R=1

= x(1 - ln R)
```

As we can see, `√x ≠ x(1 - ln R)`.

These distributions show up as:

[image: Probability that the function is less than a given value]

The y-axis gives the probability that the line (`random()²` or `random() · random()`) is less than the x axis.

We see that for the `random() · random()`, the probability of large numbers is significantly less.

#### Density functions

I guess the most revealing thing is to differentiate (`½x ^ -½` and `- ln x`) and plot the probability density functions:

[image: Probabilities of each number's occurring]

This shows the probability of each `x` in relative terms. So the probability that `x` is large (`> 0.5`) is about twice for the `random()²` variant.

Comment: Very good and detailed explanation. How long did it take you to create that answer? (I'm curious)

Comment: @Sirac 1-2 hours. Most of it was relearning `matplotlib` (and math), though.

Answer (score 13):

Let's simplify the problem somewhat. Consider throwing two dice and multiplying the result against throwing one die and squaring it. In the first case you have a 1 in 36 chance of throwing a double 1, therefore a 1 in 36 chance the product is 1. On the other hand the second case obviously has a 1 in 6 chance that the square is 1. The same applies for a double 6, so the extremes are much more probable when squaring.

The same follows when you use random floats: you are much less likely to get two random values at the extremes than you are to get a single value, so very small or very large values will come up much more often when squaring then when multiplying two independent values.

Comment: This is why in the middle of the list you see more similar distribution. Since random potentially returns zero, you also end up with the results skewed there too - note lst3 has many zeros.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now. I still have to think about it, but it gets more clear now. I never though such a simple question is so hard to understand.